# Regex to update form input multiple indexes in nested sortable form

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms

I have a list of simple form inputs, which are sortable and the user can add more rows to the form.

the name attributes are fairly straight forward:

```
field_id_3[0][options][html_data]
field_id_3[1][options][html_data]
field_id_3[2][options][html_data]
```

I have a fairly simple updateindexes method which looks like so:

```
$container.find('.' + opts.rowClass).each(function(rowCount) {

  regex = /^(.*)\[(?:[0-9]+)\](.*)$/;

  $(this).find('input, select, textarea').each(function(fieldCount) {
    $field = $(this);
    if ($field.attr('name')) {
      var fieldName = $field.attr('name').replace(regex, '$1[' + rowCount + ']$2');
      $field.attr('name', fieldName);
    }
  });
});
```

This all seems to work well, but now I'm needing to introduce new elements which too are sortable and nested. I'm now writing a second updateindexes method which will handle the nested indexes only.

The name attributes are along the lines of

```
field_id_3[0][options][html_data]
field_id_3[1][options][html_data]
field_id_3[2][options][list_items][0][item]
field_id_3[3][options][list_items][1][item]
field_id_3[4][options][html_data]
```

What I'm stuck with is modifying the regex pattern so that the replacements of the first array index, and any second array indexes are independent of eachother in the two update indexes methods.

How can i target the first [key] attribute and the second [key] attribute independantly with regex?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `field_id_3[][options][list_items][][item]` and letting the browser (or is it the receiving server?) look after the indexes? This certainly works with the simple case of eg. `field_id_3[]`. Deep naming is unknown territory.

Comment: Some of the items/rows have multiple values, I simplified for the example.

Comment: So without explicit indexes the fields won't associate together properly?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach from what you requested, in which a worker function renumbers all indexes in accordance with parameters passed to it.

Here's the worker function :

```
var indexFinder = /\[(?:[0-9]+)\]/g; //defined once to give reIndex() a little less work to do.

function reIndex(str) {
    str = str.replace(indexFinder, '[]');
    for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; i++){
        str = str.replace('[]', '['+arguments[i]+']');
    }
    return str;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QyELs/)**

The challenge is then to devise a loop structure from which to call reIndex().

Something like this maybe, assuming list_items are grouped inside suitable containers :

```
var itemGroupSelector = '.itemGroup'; //or similar
var fieldSelector = 'input, select, textarea';

$container.find('.' + opts.rowClass).each(function(rowCount, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    $row.find(fieldSelector).each(function(i, field) {
        $field = $(field);
        if ($field.attr('name')) {
            var fieldName = reIndex($field.attr('name'), rowCount);
            $field.attr('name', fieldName);
        }
    });

    $row.find(itemGroupSelector).each(function(itemCount, itemGroup) {
        $(itemGroup).find(fieldSelector).each(function(i, field) {
            $field = $(field);
            if ($field.attr('name')) {
                var fieldName = reIndex($field.attr('name'), rowCount, itemCount);
                $field.attr('name', fieldName);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There's still a bit of work to do but I'm sure this can be made to work.